# Display plot on intraday only

Tags: plot, display

Pine Script question:

I want to display a 9ema plot on intraday charts only. When I use this code:

```
//@version=4

ema9 = ema(close, 9)
plot(ema9, '9ema', color.white, 2, display = iff(timeframe.isintraday, display.all, display.none))
```

I get "Cannot call 'plot' with 'display'=integer. The argument should be of type: const integer"

The documentation states that [display.all](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_display%7Bdot%7Dall) and [display.none](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_display%7Bdot%7Dnone) **are** const integer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to display the ema on intraday charts. In this I have returned plot value only if chart is intraday other wise "na" is returned which wont plot anything.

```
ema9 = ema(close, 9)
plot(timeframe.isintraday?ema9:na, title='9ema', color=color.white, linewidth=2)
```